# Is there a way to get a callback at completion of individual css animation keyframe?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to dynamically change content of HTML element while it is being animated with keyframes. but i need to synchronized these manipulations with the keyframes. if there is a callback i can get at the completion of given keyframe, that would be very helpful, but i couldn't find any indications such callbacks exist. hopefully someone knows otherwise or has another idea how to synch with keyframe animation?